# Vuetify <v-app-bar> can hide buttons but can't show

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In my app I have a `<v-app-bar>` and I have buttons in the app bar like so:

```
<v-tooltip bottom>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn
           @click="showModel = true"
           icon
           class="mx-2 white--text"
           v-bind="attrs"
           v-on="on"
           v-if="showTDT"
           ><v-icon>mdi-rotate-3d</v-icon></v-btn
         ></template
       >
       <span>3D Tour</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

If I start the variable `showTDT` as `true` when page loads then I can change it to `false` and hide the button. But I cannot seem to show it again. If I start the variable as `false` and try to change it to `true` the button never shows. Changing the variable to `true` from `false` doesn't make the button show again. I am at a loss. What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I have an example:

```
<v-app-bar :clipped-left="clipped" fixed app>
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer" />
</v-app-bar>
```

And inside:

```
data(){
   clipped: true,
   drawer: false,
   fixed: false,
}
```

i hope that´s rigth

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).